# Bash script to return all elements given an extension, without using print flags

Tags: bash, sed

I want to create shell script that search inside all folders of the actual directory and return all files that satisfy some condition, but without using any print flag.
(Here the condition is  to end with .py)

What I have done:

```
find . -name '*.py'| sed -n 's/\.py$//p'
```

The output:

```
./123
./test
./abc/dfe/test3
./testing
./test2
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
123
test
test3
testing
test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec sh -c 'for f; do f=${f%.py}; echo "${f##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

If GNU `basename` is an option, you can simplify this to

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec basename -s .py {} +
```

POSIX `basename` is a little more expensive, as you'll have to call it on every file individually:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec basename {} .py \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU grep instead of sed:

```sh
find . -name '*.py' | grep -oP '[^/]+(?=\.py$)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If portability is not a concern, this is a very readable option:

`find . -name '*.py' | xargs basename -a`

This is also differentiated from chepner's answer in that it retains the `.py` file ending in the output.

<strike>I'm not familiar with the `-exec` flag, and I'm sure his one-liners can be customized to do the same, but I couldn't do so off the top of my head.</strike>

Chepner's version achieves the same with the small modification:

`find . -name '*.py' -exec basename {} \;`

if you want the literal output from `find` and didn't intend to drop the file endings when you used dummy variables (`123`,`test`, etc.) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`find` shows entries relative to where you ask it to search, you can simply replace the `.` with a `*`:

```
find * -name '*.py'| sed -n 's/\.py$//p'
```

(Be aware that this skips top level hidden directories)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
find . -name '*.py*'  2>/dev/null | parallel echo "{/.}"
```